# load a file for conjunctive normal form into a list of lists

Tags: python, conjunctive-normal-form

I have written some code to load a cnf from a file which store the cnf according to the standard described [here](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/cnf/cnf.html).

the file is:

```
c  simple_v3_c2.cnf      // lines bigining by c are comments
c  
p cnf 3 2                // the line bigining by p is the description of the pb
1 -3 0                   // folowing lines are formulation of the pb, with 0 as ending caractere
2 3 -1 0
```

I want to load it into [[1, -3][2,3,-1]]

The code I have written works, but it seems ugly to me. I would be interested in having some feedback on it. (I am new to python).

```
def loadCnfFile(fileName='example.cnf'):
""" retourne une liste de listes d'entiers decrivants la forme normale conjonctive"""
cnf=[]
cnfFile = open(fileName, 'r')
for line in cnfFile:
    if line[0]!="c" and line[0]!="p":
        l=line.split("0")[0].strip().split(" ")
        m=[]
        for k in l:
            m.append(int(k))
        cnf.append(m)
cnfFile.close()
return cnf
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `list comprehension`:

```
In [66]: with open("example.cnf") as f:
        print [map(int,line.split("0")[0].split()) for line in f if line and \
                            not (line.startswith("c") or line.startswith("p"))]
   ....:     
[[1, -3], [2, 3, -1]]
```

or:

```
with open("example.cnf") as f:
         x= lambda y,c:y.startswith(c)
         print [map(int,line.split("0")[0].split()) for line in f if line and \
                                not any(x(line,z) for z in ("c","p"))]
   ....:     
[[1, -3], [2, 3, -1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the best feedback on your code would be to rewrite it in a more "pythonic" manner. For example:

```
def cnf_lines(path):
    """Yields cnf lines as lists from the file."""

    with open(path) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if not line.startswith(('c', 'p')):
                items = map(int, line.split())
                yield items[:-1]
```

Key points:

- PEP-8 conformance (no camelCase in python please)
- context managers (`with`) for file operations
- generators (`yield`) instead of accumulating lists

NB: this code is intentionally simplified and does not fully support the specs you linked to.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however, maybe you can explain me something else: I don't understand why all the answers use `not line.startswith("c")` instead of `line[0]!="c"`. Is there an advantage in using startswith that I am unaware of ? (To me, line[0] is more explicit than another-method-that-I-have-never-seen like .startswith(), but I guess this makes the difference between an experienced programmer and a noob =).

Comment: @edelans: there are a few reasons to prefer `startswith`, one of them is its ability to check for _multiple_ possible prefixes at once.

Answer (score 1):

Ashwini'S code is correct and appealing to an experienced programmer (thank you), but for someone new to python (what you seem to be) maybe a plain for-loop is easier to understand:

```
result = []
with open("example.cnf") as f:
    for line in f:
        if not (line.startswith("c") or line.startswith("p")):
            result.append([int(x) for x in line.rstrip("0").rstrip("0\n").split()])
```

Comment: I'm not sure I like `line.split("0")`. What if they get something like `1 2 10 3`?

Comment: You're right. I adjusted my sample. Now uses rstrip("0"), so only trailing zeros are removed.

Comment: or just `rstrip("0\n")`. Will adjust my sample.

Comment: The problem with rstrip("0") is that the string ends with '\n' so 0 is not a trailing character... but I found a workaround with `line.split(" 0")[0].split()`. Thanks @thg435 for the problem anticipation ;)

Comment: @Thorsten Kranz: unless for the last 0 of the file if it's the last line =). But maybe with rstrip("0\n","0") (I didn't check if the syntax exists).

Comment: Good point. The syntax doesn't exist, but you can do `.rstrip("0").rstrip("0\n")`